# After combining my reducer using combineReducer, action is not dispatching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, single-page-application

This was my reducer file. everything works fine If I use this.
https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/9129d43c4397ff752f88739cc1f4309f

I want to split it into multiple file using combineReducer. but after splitting it, redux action is not dispatching.

This is my product reducer:

```
import { SET_PRODUCTS } from '../actionTypes';

const init = {
  products: [],
  keyword: '',
  cartItems: {},
};

const productReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  if (action.type === SET_PRODUCTS) {
    return {
      ...state,
      products: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export default productReducer;
```

and here I am combining it:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import productReducer from './productReducer';
import cartItemReducer from './cartItemReducer';
import keywordReducer from './keyWordReducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  products: productReducer,
  keyword: keywordReducer,
  cartItems: cartItemReducer,
});

export default reducers;
```

what I am missing here?

Comment: It looks ok. Is it some specific action not dispatching or any action? Maybe there is a typo

Comment: I mean it dispatching correctly If I use the big reducer file. 
So I assume, nothing is wrong on my action creator and from where I dispatching the file.

Comment: How are you dispatching your action? can you show an example?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/646e5baed529b8547517077b8927c38a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given wrong initial state on productReducer.
It should be a plain empty array. and you should return only the products array.. not the whole state.

```
const productReducer = (state = [], { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === SET_PRODUCTS) {
    return [...payload]
  }
  return state;
};
```

or if you dont want to change the productReducer, you have to consume the store variable using store.products.products.

`const products = useSelector((state) => state.products.products)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a mistake in the reducer function

```
const productReducer = (state = init, action) => {
  if (action.type === SET_PRODUCTS) {
    // here you have to return the new state for `state.products` and not for `state`
    return {
      ...state,
      products: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

Try this reducer instead

```
const productReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === SET_PRODUCTS) {
    return [...action.payload];
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: it didn't even trigger the action.
Here is how I dispatch it:
https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/646e5baed529b8547517077b8927c38a

Comment: This is the code of SetProducts action.

this action is not triggered when I use combineReducer. 
but without combineReducerit works like a charm!

https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/646e5baed529b8547517077b8927c38a#file-setproducts-js

Comment: No idea how does action not getting dispatched if only reducer changes. There is no connection between those 2. Maybe there is some other change which you have not mentioned?